# How do you determine the pressure of water at the surface?

Tags: bernoulli-equation

Using Bernoulli's equation, how would you determine the pressure of the water at the surface in a vacuum?

I have tried figuring this out and I believe it would be 0pa due to the height of water above being 0m, but this would not make sense using the equation.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but in a vacuum would there be a proper surface? i would think the water would evaporate and dissipate. i suppose you could consider the beading that would occur to be based primarily on potential energy and the pressure induced would be mainly due to surface tension, bonds and ionization. just spit balling, didnt think this out fully so leaving as a comment.

Comment: @GaretClaborn on earth at room temperature, there's really not - water boils in a vacuum at room temperature. However at a very low temp or in a stronger gravitational field I think it is conceivable that there could be a surface?